# Creating a new column within multiple datasets with a loop function

Tags: r, loops

I have multiple datasets named `Dataset.1`, `Dataset.2`, .., that I created trough a loop.

Now I would like to create an new column in each dataset just like:

```
require(plyr)
Dataset.1 <- ddply(Dataset.1, "Col_x", transform, Col_y = mean(Col_y, na.rm=TRUE))
Dataset.2 <- ddply(Dataset.2, "Col_x", transform, Col_y = mean(Col_y, na.rm=TRUE))
Dataset.3 <- ddply(Dataset.3, "Col_x", transform, Col_y = mean(Col_y, na.rm=TRUE))
Dataset.4 <- ddply(Dataset.4, "Col_x", transform, Col_y = mean(Col_y, na.rm=TRUE))
.....
```

As my number of datasets is not always the same, I fell like a loop function would be the right way to do this. I just don't know how.

The start of the loop in my opinion should be someting like:

```
dataset_names <- ls(pattern = "Dataset.")
for(i in 1:length(dataset_names)) {
.....
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Stef

Comment: Are you looking for `assign(dataset_names[i], ddply(get(dataset_names[i]), "Col_x", transform, Col_y = mean(Col_y, na.rm=TRUE)))` for your loop?

Comment: I also posted the same just now...

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve with `ddply(Dataset.1, "Col_x", transform, Col_y = mean(Col_y, na.rm=TRUE))`. Could you add a reproductible example and the output you expect?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your dataset name pattern is same as you mentioned then try this

```
NumberOfDataset #Assume this variable have number of dataset you have
for(i in 1:NumberOfDataset){
  datasetName = paste0('Dataset.',i)
  assign(datasetName, ddply(get(datasetName), "Col_x", transform, Col_y = mean(Col_y, na.rm=TRUE))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `assign` and `get` function to call a object by a character vector of length one.

```
# Simulate some data
set.seed(2014)
Dataset.1 <- data.frame(Col_x=rbinom(n=100,size=3,prob=0.6), Col_y=rnorm(100))
Dataset.2 <- data.frame(Col_x=rbinom(n=100,size=3,prob=0.6), Col_y=rnorm(100))

# Before transformation
head(Dataset.1)
#   Col_x      Col_y
# 1     2  0.4614496
# 2     3  0.3350788
# 3     2 -0.8645477
# 4     2  1.1806771
# 5     2 -0.1938235
# 6     3  0.8250026
head(Dataset.2)
#   Col_x      Col_y
# 1     2  0.2342058
# 2     2 -2.3599130
# 3     1 -0.7225682
# 4     1  0.2513051
# 5     1  1.0576962
# 6     0  0.3083427


require(plyr)

# Loop over the datasets
for(a_dataset in ls(pattern = "Dataset.")){

  original_df <- get(a_dataset)

  transformed_df <- ddply(.data=original_df, .variables="Col_x", .fun=summarize, mean = mean(Col_y, na.rm=TRUE))

  assign(x=paste0("summarised.",a_dataset), value=transformed_df)
}

summarised.Dataset.1
#   Col_x         mean
# 1     0  0.235238326
# 2     1 -0.171010231
# 3     2  0.261661820
# 4     3  0.009241608
summarised.Dataset.1
#   Col_x         mean
# 1     0  0.235238326
# 2     1 -0.171010231
# 3     2  0.261661820
# 4     3  0.009241608
```